# How can I crop several and random batches from an image?

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image of size (224 x 224) and I want to extract a number of random patches from the original image using Matlab (let say 5 patches). One of these patch should be at the centre of the original image. The patch size is (128 x 128).

I have tried this to crop just the centre patch:

```
II = imread('img.png')
[p3, p4] = size(II);
q1 = 50; // size of the crop box
i3_start = floor((p3-q1)/2); % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i3_stop = i3_start + q1;

i4_start = floor((p4-q1)/2);
i4_stop = i4_start + q1;

II = II(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop, :);
figure ,imshow(II);
```

Comment: If you want the sample from the center, how is it a random sample?

Comment: An image is just a matrix. You can access elements and ranges of your matrix to extract the patches. Take a look at this [LINK](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) for Matrix indexing.

Comment: One of them should be at the centre and then we can move the centre of the next patch to the left, right, up, or down to get another patch. Yes, I know the Matlab good and I've tried this code:

Comment: II = imread('img.png')
[p3, p4] = size(II);
q1 = 50; // size of the crop box
i3_start = floor((p3-q1)/2); % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i3_stop = i3_start + q1;

i4_start = floor((p4-q1)/2);
i4_stop = i4_start + q1;

II = II(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop, :);
figure ,imshow(II);

Comment: Please, can you put the code inside the question and formatted as code?

Comment: And while you're editing your code into the question, please add the results and how they differ from what you expect.

Comment: What warning do you get with round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to accomplish this in the following way:

```
A=imread('Lena.bmp');%sample image
rnd_x = randperm(size(A,1)-128,5);%choose 5 tandom unique points on x-axis
rnd_y = randperm(size(A,2)-128,5);%choose 5 tandom unique points on y-axis
for ii = 1:5
    piece{ii} = A((rnd_x(ii):(rnd_x(ii)+127)),(rnd_y(ii):(rnd_y(ii)+127)),1:3);%Convert chosen numbers to image pieces
    figure(ii)
    imshow(piece{ii});
end
```

This takes image like this:
[image]

This gives 5 pics like this:

[image]

Here our image size is 512x512. So, if we want to cut the 128x128 piece from it, we need to seek from 385x385 grid (512-127). We find 5 random points on the grid expressed in `rnd_x` and `rnd_y`. Finally, we take the found points as the upper-left corners of the pieces and construct 128x128 images from them. The 5 pieces are recorded in piece cell array.

EDIT: forgot to add how to extract the center patch. The following code performs the task:

```
A=imread('Lena.bmp');%sample image
if mod(size(A,1),2)
A = A(1:(end-1),:,:);
end
if mod(size(A,2),2)
A = A(:,1:(end-1),:);
end
while size(A,1) > 128
A = A(2:(end-1),:,:);
end
while size(A,2) > 128
A = A(:,2:(end-1),:);
end
imshow(A)
```

The code removes one pixel from each side until we get the 128-pixel image.

Comment: Dear Brainkz & BlackAdder
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Careful! In your code, if you load a color image (3 channels) and call `size` with only two outputs, you will have an incorrect value for `p4`.

Use three outputs when loading images to avoid this problem: 
`[nrows ncols nchannels] = size(II);`
Your code correctly extracts a (`q1` x `q1`) from the center of the image.

If you want a random patch just generate a random integer for the top-left column of the patch with the correct range to ensure that it doesn't fall outside the image. You can generate random integers using the function `randi`.

```
i3_start = randi(floor((p3-q1));
i4_start = randi(floor((p4-q1));
```

The rest of the code is the same. If you want several patches you can generate several values when calling the `randi` function with a second and third parameter for the desired number of rows and columns. And then process each patch inside a for loop.

BTW: In the third line you have an invalid Matlab comment (use `%` for comments). Also you should name your variables with more intuitive names.

Eg: `[nrows ncols nchannels] = size(II);`